# Помогите выравнить контент по центру

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, itemtouchhelper

Нужно сделать так, чтоб единица начиналась не под шапкой, а слева от сайдбара. Помогите пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.graficlogo {
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: #00BCF1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#sidebar {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar h3 {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #00BCF1;
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #00BCF1;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  height: 50%;
}

.footer_social p {
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img class="graficlogo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- Контент -->1
</main>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h3> Каталог товаров </h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""> Телефоны и асскесуары </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Мужская одежда </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Женская одежда </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Детская одежда </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Бытовые приборы </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Уличные площадки </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Компьютерные акссесуары </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer_container">
    <div class="footer_social">
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим можно на grid сделать. Но вам бы разобраться с вложенностью блоков. Если `sidebar` по дизайну не распространяется на `header` и `footer`, то он должен быть частью контекста `main`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.graficlogo {
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: #00BCF1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#sidebar {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar h3 {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #00BCF1;
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  /*
position: absolute;
*/
  background: #00BCF1;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  height: 50%;
}

.footer_social p {
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a" "b c" "d d";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px;
}

header {
  grid-area: a;
}

main {
  grid-area: b;
}

#sidebar {
  grid-area: c;
}

footer {
  grid-area: d;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img class="graficlogo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- Контент -->1
</main>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h3> Каталог товаров </h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""> Телефоны и асскесуары </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Мужская одежда </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Женская одежда </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Детская одежда </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Бытовые приборы </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Уличные площадки </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> Компьютерные акссесуары </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer_container">
    <div class="footer_social">
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
      <p>Мы в социальных сетях!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @БогданТаран у ответа есть кнопочка "отметить решением". )